# Question on transformation of second order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In many literature related to ODE BVP, people write a second order ODE

\begin{equation}y''=f_0(x,y,y')\end{equation}

as

\begin{equation}y''=f(x,y)\end{equation}

It seems that the first equation can be transformed to the second form, but I don't know.

(Question) Is there a general transformation from the first one to the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer is: no, there is no general transformation to remove the dependence on $y'$.

However, a large number of second order boundary value problems studied in the literature are *linear*, i.e. of Sturm-Liouville type:
$$
 y'' + a_1(x) y' + a_2(x) y = f(x). \tag{1}
$$
In these cases, you can apply the Liouville transform
$$ y(x) = z(x) \text{exp}\,\left[ \int^x -\frac{1}{2} a_1(\xi)\,\text{d}\xi\right]
$$
which transforms $(1)$ into
$$
 z'' + b(x) z = f(x)\,\text{exp}\left[ \int^x \frac{1}{2} a_1(\xi)\,\text{d}\xi\right],
$$
where
$$
 b(x) = -\frac{1}{2} a_1' - \frac{1}{4} a_1^2 + a_2.
$$